# Colon vs semicolon in instructions

Tags: punctuation

I have consulted many punctuation guides, but I am still uncertain on which to use when writing instructions. For example:

```
Pick a player: she cannot participate in the first round.
or
Pick a player; she cannot participate in the first round.
or even
Pick a player, she cannot participate in the first round.
```

Personally I feel the version with the comma is weird, but I always hesitate between the other two options.

Edit: I would like this strategy to be versatile enough that I can use it with many different instructions, so I'm adding another example:

```
Pick a team: join it in two rounds.
```

In this case, I feel that punctuation is essential because something like

```
Pick a team and join it in two rounds.
```

makes the timing more ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not convinced *either* work as separators between an "imperative" instruction and a "parenthetical" statement like this. If they're both part of the *same* sentence, a comma followed by ***who cannot*** [more precisely, ***will not be able to***] ***participate...*** Or enclose that "caveat" in brackets (explicitly "parenthetical"). OR - just use a full stop, and treat it as a second sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not so sure these added clauses are really parenthetical. See the new example I've added. In that one, it would make no sense to put in in brackets.

Comment: I wouldn't use punctuation in this sentence at all; I'd remove the punctuation and replace *she* with *who*: *Pick a player who cannot participate in the first round.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (a) Pick a player: she cannot participate in the first round.
>
> (b) Pick a player; she cannot participate in the first round.
>
> (c) Pick a player, she cannot participate in the first round

**Option (c)** uses a comma to join two main clauses (they could stand as complete sentences, the first imperative and the second declarative, and indeed a full stop is a valid alternative here). Though 'comma splices' as they are known are not always (as some would claim) verboten, this example is better discarded.

**Option (a)** uses the colon; the most general 'job description' of a colon is 'a stop used to introduce / lead on to something relevant to the preceding text'. So this certainly licenses the colon here. On the minus side is the fact that the colon is old-fashioned, and usually replaced by a dash. The nature of the dash (em-; en- ...) is not absloutely prescribed, though the em-dash is generally favoured (oops; favored) in the States.

**Option (b)** has the semicolon, whose principal usage is to separate semantically close main clauses. So here, it is fine, if a little academic-looking.

If you want a purely opinion-based recommendation:

> (d) Pick a player (but note that she cannot participate in the first
>   round).

This has all already been covered in various different threads (my excuse for not searching out multiple references), but I thought it might be useful to have a compare-and-contrast answer.